# Shortcut overview list: Eclipse - NetBeans - IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea, shortcut

Does anyone have an overview list with shortcuts for: Eclipse - NetBeans - IntelliJ ?

I used to be an eclipse development master, but some dude at the office moved the java environment to NetBeans, while Android forced IntelliJ (Android Studio) on the eclipse users

I'm happy with the migrations to NetBeans and Android Studio (IntelliJ), while also using eclipse.

But, I'm a lost development master without a list with shortcuts. I would love to have an **overview** with the **shortcuts** of the **3 environments next to each other**.
Help please.

Comment: This is only for IntelliJ, but it's what I used to learn them all: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a PDF with popular IDE shortcuts for all three - Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA and NetBeans - at [RebelLabs](http://pages.zeroturnaround.com/IDE-Shortcuts.html)

Comment: And much more useful reports there!

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans go to Tools >> Options >> Keymap.

You can select a netbeans, Eclipse or Intellij profile and work with the shortcuts of your choice in netbeans.

Selecting the profile will also show you a searchable list of shortcuts valid for the selected IDE environment.